# NVIDIA CUDA and linux

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-10.10

This Lenovo Z570 laptop comes with NVIDIA GEforce GT520M with optimus technology.

I'm trying to install CUDA on Ubuntu 10.10. I downloaded a dev driver from the NVIDIA site.

After installation X server is not started. Nothing is displayed on screen, however i'm able to login through recovery mode(by using failsafeX).

How can this be solved?

Comment: First thing, install a recent Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 2):

This [Ruyk article](http://www.ruyk.com/tech/?p=68) explains how to install and configure Cuda and Nvidia Optimus for Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Here is the [most recent Wayback Machine page mirror: **CUDA + Nvidia Optimus in Ubuntu 11.04**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181013162047/http://www.ruyk.com/tech/?p=68). The Ruyk website has changed dramatically in 12 years, several domains/hosts/site structures iterations. All blog posts (and content except basic CV/links) seem to be gone.